# Migrate AWS ECS cluster IPV4 to IPV6

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to avoid this new cost ([public IPv4](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/)) in aws for small projects because it will represent a big percentage of the cost.

In my ECS cluster, I use EC2 instances as capacity providers, therefore, I followed [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html) to make every new EC2 instance use IPV6 instead of IPV4 -- which worked.

However these instances are not joining the cluster to be a capacity provider, so the services will not run properly. This cluster was working fine with IPV4. I've tried different configurations in the subnets like:

- Enable resource name DNS A record on launch
- Enable resource name DNS AAAA record on launch
- Hostname type: Resource name
- Hostname type: IP name
- Enable DNS64

Also, my security groups already support inbounds and outbounds for both types (IPV4 / IPV6)

Am I missing something or ECS doesn't support this configuration (at least with EC2)? If that is the case, do you have a suggestion on how I can reduce this IPV4 cost? For instance, could I avoid this cost using ECS with Fargate?

I know that Fargate cost is bigger than EC2, but maybe EC2 + IPV4 could be more expensive than Fargate using IPV6

EDIT 1:
This is my current route table
[image]

EDIT 2:
I was able to `ping6 www.google.com` which means the instance has an internet connection. However, checking the agent log (/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log) I got the error:

```
health check [HEAD http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata] failed with error: Head \"http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:51678: connect: connection refused" module=healthcheck.go
```

Comment: Can you SSH into one of the EC2 instances and verify it has access to the Internet (using something like a `curl` command)? It sounds like it can't access the ECS API to register itself with the cluster. If you don't have a VPC endpoint in the VPC for the ECS service, then the instances would need Internet access to connect to the ECS API.

Comment: @MarkB This could be the case to test cURL command, I'm trying to connect to my instance through vpc endpoint, since I cant use ssh without a public dns hostname

Comment: You should be able to use the public IPv6 address to SSH into it.

Comment: @MarkB I was able to ping6 google.com, so I don't think the problem is internet access